Angular: Can I edit a enum based on a conditional?
So I've created an enum to hold the colors that are used a lot across my application.
export enum SeverityColor {
    None = '#2196F3',
    Low = '#39B54a',
    Medium = '#FCEE21',
    High = '#F7931E',
    Critical = '#F44336',
}

Now we're wanting to add a theme switch from dark to light mode and with that these colors will need to change depending on which mode the app is in. It is probably not best practice, but is there a way I can update this Enum based on a condition? It would be so much easier than finding every place I'm referencing this and changing how that works.
Or does anyone have a suggestion on a better way to do this?
Thanks.

Couldn't you just turn the enum into a variable?

Yes, but that would also include changing all references.

You would only have to refactor instances of that enum used in other places (ie another control imports it and has a variable that uses this enum type), but if this enum is only being referenced then no refactor of other controls would be needed because the import and usaged would remain the same.

One clarifying question, how are you using these elsewhere?  Are you just referring to them or are you assigning the value to other variables?  Considering that you are working in an Angular app, are you even sure that changing these values at the enum level will comply with the lifecycle of your angular components? (ie if you assigned the value from the enum to a template bound member variable.)  Personally I would recommend just taking the hit and refactoring now to an architecture thats appropriate for what you are trying to do, going the enum route will just cause more trouble later on IMO

This is more of a typescript question. To simplify, enums in typescript basically compile down to a plain javascript object. That means, from a javascript perspective, it would be possible to write something like this:
SeverityColor.Low = '#BADA55';

However, typescript will complain if you do this, saying that Low is readonly. You can walk around this by type asserting to any, like this:
(SeverityColor as any).Low = '#BADA55';

Now I don't think this is a very good idea, but there you go.

I tried using a ternary operator within the enum, but ran into this problem:
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number' as required for computed enum member values. My simple understanding of it is that there is difference between const-based and string-based enum, and in a string-based enum the string values are treated before assigned to the member key. I think I remember solving it or finding a work around a little while ago either using a type or const assertion or casting the member value, but I think your best solution is to use: const isDark = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme:dark)").matches or const currentTheme = document.documentElement.getAttribute("data-theme") to make a decision between two sets of enum SeverityColor for light and dark mode.
